# No entiendo por que grid me arroja un error

Tags: css, grid

les comento que quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```css
.cart-box{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 32% 50% 18%;
}
```

Pero me resalta el 50% del centro y me dice:

specifies, as a space-separated track list, the line names and track sizing functions of the grid.

Syntax: none |  |  | subgrid ?

no puedo dejar este sistema asi de grid. aguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no tiene nada de malo:

```css
.cart-box {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 32% 50% 18%;
}

.cart-box > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-box">
  <div>32%</div>
  <div>50%</div>
  <div>18%</div>
</div>
```

La descripción que comentas simplemente es una descripción que te muestra tu editor de código para que sepas qué es y cómo se usa esa propiedad.

[image: screenshot en mi editor]